# base_url() not getting translated

Tags: codeigniter

I have inherited an app that was built with Code Igniter. I've set up the environment and loaded the app on a new machine and I'm having an issue with the call to base_url() not working.

Here is the code as it is in the view:

```
<a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start">Start Study Analysis &raquo; </a>
```

When the page is rendered, this is the URL that is created:

> `<a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start">Start Study Analysis &raquo;</a>`

It appears that the function call is not taking place and the code is being inserted as plain text. I've looked at the config.php file and the base_url is set in there. The helper is being loaded in the autoload.php file and I've even tried to load the helper in the view.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: If the base_url is properly set to your new url in your config.php file, then maybe someone has defined it again somewhere else?

Comment: I've edited the post, please note the formatting instructions and tools for future reference, and please edit the code if I have made a mistake.

Comment: The code is correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @David: So, `http://localhost/wizard/<?=base_url();?>index.php/study/start` appears in the actual source code - the entire thing? Your actual base url **and** the php code that generates it?

Comment: That is what appears in the html when you view the source code of the rendered page.

Comment: Actuall, this is what is in the html code: <a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start"> I copied the original from the url bar instead of the html

Comment: That's what I suspected, I added one more piece to my answer, but other than that I'm out of ideas. Are you ***sure*** this ***only*** happens when you call `base_url()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code as it is in the view:
>
> `a href="< ?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start">Start Study Analysis &raquo; /a>`

Either this is a formatting mistake in your post, or you just have a really mangled link there.

I'm going to take a guess that you do have a space between your `<` and `?=`, which would indeed cause the code not to be parsed as php, but instead as broken text/html.

`%20` is a url encoded space character, so it makes sense that this is what you'd see in your url.

Make sure there are no spaces in your PHP opening tag:

- `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` and not `< ?php echo base_url(); ?>`
- `<?= base_url(); ?>` and not `< ?= base_url(); ?>`

> There isn't a space there. I needed to add it [for formatting the post]

The only other thing I can think of is that short tags are not enabled, but I admit that I do not know if this would be your result if that was the case. Try using `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`, or enabling the `rewrite_short_tags` option in your `config.php`. This certainly is not an issue specific to `base_url()` or anything similar, your php tags are getting parsed as plain text so what's inside them does not matter at all.

Comment: There isn't a space there. I needed to add it so that the function call wasn't made. This is really frustrating because it's working where it isn't supposed to, but isn't working where it is. The other missing <> are also not mistakes, but deleted so that the rest of the text would be shown as they should be.

Comment: Try this again code in view file: <a href="<?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start">Start Study Analysis » /a>        Resulting HTML: http://localhost/wizard/<?= base_url();?>index.php/study/start

Comment: I tried to put the exact code in the original post, but it keeps getting translated into html.

Comment: I put the exact code back into the main post. I'm assuming that you can edit my post so that you can see it.